# PayPal IPN Variable receiver_email

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have created a successful PayPal IPN script which imports the result into my database but I would like to know if there is any way I can set a custom `$receiver_email` for the transaction. The problem I run into when doing this is that the IPN is not set up on some accounts.

To put it into context I am creating an auction site where buyers can pay for items and the seller (receiver_email) needs to change to send the payment to them.

If there any way I can get round this problem? If someone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to change the   mail sent by paypal, or the mail sent by your site?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. The IPN settings are set at the account level, so it is up to the receiving paypal account to notify their IPN system.

You would be better off (from a technical point of view, IANAL and this isn't advice on legal issues) having buyers all paying into a central clearing account which you then use to separately pay the sellers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [PayPal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/). A note about this though: one account - probably you as the main application owner - must have a PayPal business account. The other accounts that receive a payment only need a personal account.

PayPal provides an SDK with samples for the Adaptive Payments on [Github](http://paypal.github.io/). Select `Adaptive Payments` from the menu on the left. There are samples for multiple languages that should be able to get you started.